# Apache Solr - indexing a DB table appears to retrieve more records than contained in the table

Tags: apache, solr, import, indexing

I'm very new to Solr so If I am saying something that doesn't make sense please let me know.

I've recently setup Solr 4.0 beta and it is working quite well. It is setup with DIH to read a view from a MySQL DB. The view contains about 20 million rows and 16 columns. A number of the columns have a lot of NULL values. The performance of the DB is quite good  -I get sub-second query times against the view when I run a query manually.

I pointed Solr at the view and it began the index process. I came back four hours later to check on it and discovered that not only was it still indexing but that it reported as fetching 200+ million.

Am I mis-understanding how Solr works? I was under the assumption that it would fetch the same number of rows as what is in the DB  -which is about 20 million. Or, is it actually counting each field as an item fetched? Or, even worse, is it in some kind of loop?

I did some prior testing with a small sub-set of the data from the very same view by limiting the query to 100,000 records. On completion, it reported as having fetched exactly 100,000. I am not getting any warnings/errors in the logs either.

Any ideas on what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

The number is represent row in db. Could you post your db-data-config.xml file? I think you should check your sql again.